# Different image and background color depending on page type

Tags: php, posts

Here is the HTML/PHP and CSS code for a part of my page

**HTML/PHP**

```
<?php
$product_pages_args = array(
    'meta_key' => '_wp_page_template',
    'meta_value' => 'page_library_html_content.php',
    'hierarchical' => '0'
);
$product_pages = get_pages( $product_pages_args );
?>

<?php
foreach ( $product_pages as $product_page ) {
    $author_id =  get_post_field('post_author', $product_page->ID );
    $author_details = get_user_by( 'id', $author_id );
    $author_name = $author_details->first_name . ' ' . $author_details->last_name;  

    echo '<div id="posts" class="flex_100"><div class="posts_bar"></div>';
    echo '<div id="library_title"><a href="' . get_permalink( $product_page->ID ) . '">' . $product_page->post_title  . '</a></div>';
    echo '<div class="library-content">' . get_post_field('post_content', $product_page->ID ) . '</div>';
     echo '<div class="library-author">Tutorial Instructor:  ' . $author_name . '</div>';
    echo '<div class="library-author-av">' . get_avatar( $author_id , 32 ) . '</div></div>';;
```

**CSS**

```
#posts {
float: left;
width: 48%;
background-color: #FFF;
height: 300px;
margin-left: 20px;
margin-top:20px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
}
#posts:before {
content: "";
position: absolute;
z-index: 2;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0px;
left: 60%;
background-image: url(http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/Techyoucation%202014%20Wordpress%20Theme/images/html.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
background-color: #39ADD1;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
border-top-right-radius: 5px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}
```

Now with this code you can see that there is a box with the post tile and content (only post's with page type (page_library_html_content.php))

What I would like to do is show only the posts with the page type:

page_library_html_content.php
page_library_css_content.php
page_library_wordpress_content.php

and the background image in

```
#posts:before
```

will change depending on the page type of the page and the background color will change too.

Is this possible and how.

Thanks

Comment: I don't quite follow which part you have trouble implementing. Do you need to change your page retrieval to retrieve pages with multiple templates assigned or what?

Comment: Sorry too many questions in one. What I need is 1) Retrieve posts from more than one page type. 2) Display different image for each result depending on the page-type the post is from 3) change the background color for each result depending on the page-type the post is from. - Thanks

Comment: Can you help me with this @Rarst

Answer (score 0):

I've used [Wordpress Conditional Tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) to add a unique class or id to the containing div of the different page types. This could work well to change the background image/color for different types.

Also, Wordpress automatically adds a [body class](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class#Page) to the `<body>` tag for each page, so that could possibly be hooked into for said unique classes or ids.